# Unknown key format when importing Private Key from Multibit to Blockchain.info

Tags: blockchain.info, private-key, multibit

I'm trying to import a Private Key from MultiBit into Blockchain.info, but get an error saying "*Error importing private key: Unknown Key Format*".

Is my MultiBit key in the wrong format or something?

Comment: What's the first letter of the private key?

Comment: `# KEEP YOUR PRIVATE KEYS SAFE !
# Anyone who can read this file can spend your bitcoin.
#
# Format:
#   <Base58 encoded private key>[<whitespace>[<key createdAt>]]
#
#   The Base58 encoded private keys are the same format as
#   produced by the Satoshi client/ sipa dumpprivkey utility.
#
#   Key createdAt is in UTC format as specified by ISO 8601
#   e.g: 2011-12-31T16:42:00Z . The century, 'T' and 'Z' are mandatory
#
L3m6g... 2015-07-26T11:37:52Z`

Comment: If you have not been successful yet, PM me, I think I can help.